# Why is the module initialize method not called?

Tags: ruby

Why is this module's `initialize` method not called when it is included in `Temp` class?

```
module Temp
  def initialize
    p "asdasd"
  end
end

class Swap
  include Temp
  def initialize
    p "m in class"
  end
end

s = Swap.new
```

> m in class

Answer (score 18):

The `Swap` class overrides the `initialize` method defined in the `Temp` module. When Ruby attempts to find a method it searches the inheritance hierarchy starting at the most derived class/module. In this case the search ends at the Swap class.

Overridden methods don't get called unless you explicitly call them with `super`. For example

```
class Swap
  include Temp
  def initialize
    p "m in  class"
    super
  end
end
```

will call `Temp#initialize` from `Swap#initialize`.

Answer (score 9):

Because you defined initialize in both the class and module, and Ruby will look for methods in its own class before moving up to other classes/module.

To see the chain of ancestors, try this

```
s = Swap.new
puts s.class.ancestors
```

You will see the chain, and know where Ruby starts to find its function.

Answer (score -3):

It only calls the constructor within scope.

If you want to invoke the modules initializer method you have to call it directly like so.

```
module Temp
  def self.initialize
    p "asdasd"
  end
end

class Swap
  include Temp
  def initialize
    p "m in class"
    Temp.initialize
  end
end

s = Swap.new
```

Comment: In this example, since scope isn't really needed, this works. But if the Temp#initialize method needs to be called in the scope of the Swap instance, you'll run into problems.

Comment: Calling `Temp.initialize` is an anti-pattern--`super` is the right way to call the `initialize` method of the super-class.