# How can I get a class and submodule to interact with the same module property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following files:

lib/b/c/d.rb

```
module B
  module C
    class D
      def initialize
        puts "#{@msg}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

a.rb

```
class A
  include B
  def initialize
    @msg = 'Hello world'
    B::C::D.new
  end
end
```

I would like the following command to output `"Hello world"`.

```
A.new
```

Instead, it just prints an empty string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified the problem significantly in the question, but I found what I was looking for. `mattr_accessor` let me define attributes on a module basis, instead of on an instance basis after including it as a mixin.

Answer (score 1):

I plugged stuff into IRB, and notice what happens when you do this, instead:

a.rb

```
class A
  include B
  attr_accessor :d
  def initialize
    @msg = 'Hello world'
    d = B::C::D.new
  end
end
```

If I then, in IRB:

```
> a= A.new
 => #<A:0x007f87149e1658 @msg="Hello world", @d=#<B::C::D:0x007f87149e1608>> 
> a.d
 => #<B::C::D:0x007f87149e1608>
```

So what appears to be going on is that you're not mixing in class `D`, you're making a local instance of class `D` within the initializer for `A`.

This seems more like what you might want:

```
class A < B::C::D
  include B
  attr_accessor :d
  def initialize
    @msg = 'Hello world'
    super
  end
end
```

If you don't want to inherit from D, see this answer: [Why is the module initialize method not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909126/why-is-the-module-initialize-method-not-called)

Comment: `you're making a local instance of class D within the initializer for A`  Initializing B::C::D, even in A, should still invokes the initializer of B::C::D, calling `puts`. The problem is that A and B::C::D are not talking to the same @msg attribute, even though B is is included into A. I want to get them to talk to the same attribute - is there any way to achieve this without changing the class signature of A?

Comment: Yes, but you would need to change `D` from a class to a `module`. Under the current set up, `A` has-a `D`, not is-a `D`.